# Index Error: List out of range in Python vscode

Tags: python, list, csv

I am student and new to Python three-tier architecture. I am just trying to follow my professor's example code

I am getting following error:

```
    customer = Customer(row[0], row[1], row[2], float(row[3]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Below is my code I am working on and my data is in my csv file as follows:

```
JACK,WHITE,1234,40000
TOM,FORD,3456,80000
SARA,JAMES,5678,15000
KATE,GREY,7896,30000
```

CODE BEGINS from Below:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from business import Customer
import os, sys

class CustomerRepository:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        current_dir=os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.__FILENAME = os.path.join(current_dir,"customer.csv")

    @property
    def FILENAME(self):
        return self.__FILENAME

    def getCustomers(self):
        customers = []
        with open(self.__FILENAME,'r', newline = "")as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)

            for row in reader:
                #print (row)'
                customer = Customer(row[0], row[1], row[2], float(row[3]))
                customers.append(customer)
                
        return customers

    def writeCustomers(self):
        with open(self.FILENAME, 'w', newline = "")as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            new_line=['1','2','3','4']
            writer.writerows(new_line)
            customers=[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]]
            for row in customers:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Thanks
BeginnerCoder

Comment: Put all code in loop under `if row:` condition, it will skip empty lines.

Comment: you mean i should add if row: before for row in reader?

Comment: After. You should put it inside loop so it could check if there's something in this row. You can replace it with `if len(row) == 4`

Comment: Un-comment the `print(row)` statement.  This will let you see why the error is happening.

Comment: @OlvinRoght  i tried using if len(row) == 4: just after my line for row in reader: but then its not reading anything when i run it, is there a way i can share my file with u because i have 4 files connected together, its a HW question but need to submit before tonight

Comment: @BeginnerCoder, remove `newline = ""` from your open statement

Comment: @JohnGordon I did that before but it is giving me the same Index error. So I am trying to run it in my bankapp file but somehow my customer repository file which I have attached in my question is not reading the values of my csv file.

Comment: If your data sample matches with actual file content condition I've suggested above should work. [Code](https://tio.run/##VY7NqsIwEIX3eYqhqwaGizVtrUIXQesvIlRBRFyIphjQpoxV8el7oxHB2RxmPs6cUz3rkylFUlHT6EtlqIbD9c7Y1dzooCAFXSvyfW8q@zNcjyerDIO2CDFs2fEQvNVijsNFPkARRjEm7szgd7ylzCVO5TxbYhR3Egyij30m7cdRnm2wk3RjFG8/54zU/qjI5ts2f27xXSfOCkNA5gG6BEd67zxdwFmVviUc0hTC3rdFRbqsX2Db2uHLug0@2rZanM3eUbHjvGn@AQ).

Comment: @OlvinRoght I removed newline=" " but it gives me same error list index out of range then i also removed newline =" " and added if len(row) == 4: after my for ..line but when i add this if line it dies not print anything

Comment: If you uncommented the `print` statement, what did it show?

Comment: if I uncommented the print statement  and runs it , it gives me same error, list index out of range

Comment: I didn't mean that uncommenting the print statement would magically fix the problem.  I meant that seeing what was printed would help us see the cause.  So, what was printed?

Comment: yes i tried to print row but its not printing anything

Comment: ['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['2', '3', '4', '5'] this is my output

Comment: and this shows why you get error - you have list `['1']` which have only one element so you can't use it with `row[1]`, `row[2]`, `row[3]`. You whould have to find out why you get list with single element.

Comment: maybe first check what you really have in file `csv` - you show `JACK,WHITE,1234,40000` but code reads `'1', '2', '3', '4'`. maybe you wrote wrong values and now it makes problem. I don't like `new_line=['1','2','3','4']` and `writer.writerows(new_line)` because you use `writerows` with char `s` at the end - and expect list of rows - like `[ [..row1..], [...row2...], ...]` but you use it with `['1','2','3','4']` and it may tread it as 4 rows: first row `1`, second row `2`, etc. so it create wrong data and later it can make problem. It needs `writerow` without char `s` at the end - for one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but I think you wrote wrong data in file and later it makes problem to read it.

You have

```
new_line = ['1','2','3','4']
writer.writerows(new_line)   # <--- with `s`
```

which use `writerows` with char `s` at the end - but it needs list of rows like

```
[ [...row1...], [...row2...], ...]
```

but you usel lise `['1','2','3','4']` .

Because string can be treated as list of char so it treats as
`[ ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'] ]` and it write `1` in first row, `2` in second row, etc. And later it read row with one element `[ '1' ]`, and row with one element `[ '2' ]` but you expect rows with four elements - and this makes problem in `Customer(row[0], row[1], row[2], float(row[3]))`

You should use `writerow` without char `s` to write it as single row

```
new_line = ['1','2','3','4']
writer.writerow(new_line)    # <--- without `s`
```

---

**EDIT:**

To make sure you could also check rows when you read it

```
for row in reader:
    if len(row) == 4:
         customer = Customer(row[0], row[1], row[2], float(row[3]))
         customers.append(customer)
    else:
        print("wrong number of data in row:" row)
        print("it should have 4 elements but it has", len(row))
```